# Insert "indent" regardless of mode

Tags: indentation

When typing docstring in python-mode, I always have issue with indentation. If I am at this point (`|` is the cursor):

```
def fn():
   """ 
   Args:|"""
```

If I press `Enter`, the cursor will move right below the `A`, and if I press `TAB`, the cursor will circle between the beginning of the line and right below `A`, while I want it indented:

```
def fn():
   """ 
   Args:
       |"""
```

Currently, I am just pressing `SPACE` 4-times (I am using 4-spaces indent) after pressing `ENTER`, but I would like to know if there is a shortcut in emacs to forcefully insert an indentation (4 spaces) regardless of the mode?

I found out that `M-RIGHT` inserts 4 spaces but when at the beginning of the line, it inserts 4 spaces without moving the cursor, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: Which indent-rules should apply inside a string? Wherefrom should Emacs that learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-u space` should insert 4 spaces at point.

Beyond this: python-mode.el provides a command `py-edit-docstring`. This opens the docstring in an own buffer. Which permits to run other text-modes while editing.

python-mode.el is available from Melpa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try `C-u space` when I get back to emacs. I'll also try `py-edit-docstring` but for small docstring I found having to switch buffer pretty annoying.

Comment: py-edit-docstring is thought for larger docstrings with own formatting resp. indent needs. Switching into the edit-buffer is done for you - it needs than C-c C-c to store edits and be back.

Comment: `C-u space` works for me, thanks. Unfortunately, I am using `elpy` and I don't have `py-edit-docstring`. But anyway, my question was not docstring-specific (this was just an example), so your answer is sufficient for me.